# Error when fitting the model using fit_generator() while applying data augmentation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow 2.1.0 on my win10. The version of cuda and cudnn is:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0
```

I wanna implement data augmentation with tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator() and especially fit_generator() method. But it returned the error:

```
2020-04-15 15:06:28.571927: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-15 15:06:29.806016: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-04-15 15:06:29.806503: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Studium/Machine Learning/check2.py", line 112, in <module>
    workers=4)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1297, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 265, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 973, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight, reset_metrics=reset_metrics)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 264, in train_on_batch
    output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 311, in train_on_batch
    output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 252, in _process_single_batch
    training=training))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 127, in _model_loss
    outs = model(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 891, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 256, in call
    return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 708, in call
    convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 860, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 891, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 197, in call
    outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 1134, in __call__
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 639, in __call__
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 238, in __call__
    name=self.name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 2010, in conv2d
    name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 1031, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 1130, in conv2d_eager_fallback
    ctx=_ctx, name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]
```

If I don't use that command fit_generator() then everything works just fine. Does anyone know where the problem is? Or how can I implement this with fit() method?

Comment: Hi  @PokeLu, Can you provide a minimum reproducible code for this error?

Comment: @TF_Support I've already changed the code. It turns out that fit() method can do the same thing. But when I try to run the code from 'https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/', the same problem occurred.

Comment: Hi @PokeLu, Can you give the code you are using for the training?

Comment: @Veeru I solved that by avoiding using fit_generator. Instead, I use fit() then no error occurs anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I don't use that command fit_generator() then everything works just
>   fine. Does anyone know where the problem is?

`fit_generator` function is deprecated, hence you are facing issues when fitting the model. Hence please use `model.fit` instead of `model.fit_generator` when using data augmentation technique.

In the official documentation, it has mentioned as below. Please refer details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator)

*Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.*

> how can I implement this with fit() method?

```
model.fit(generator_data(x_train, y_train),
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                        verbose=1)
```

Comment: @PokeLu, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it solved my problem! I've accepted the answer but unfortunately, I'm not authorized to upvote yet.@Tensorflow Warriors